# How to decode wbxml into human-readable format?

Tags: c#, xml, wbxml

I am getting a request/response from API of an application using Flidder.

Flidder shows an strange string that I think it is encoded to wbxml.

I googled a lot and finaly I gived up finding an application or site or C# library to decode my request/response that is encoded to wbxml to xml.

does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: I have never done this, but here are some older resources I just found: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21138/WBXML-Support-in-C-Handy
https://wbxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: In fiddler check the body and see the format of the body.  It may just be GZIP which is simple to decode.  You can check web for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveSync requests and responses are sent as HTTP messages. In order to reduce the size of the messages, the body is encoded in a format known as WAP Binary XML. The information about Microsoft's implementation of this protocol that is used by ActiveSync is detailed in the MS-ASWBXML document which is based in the WAP Binary XML Content Format version 1.2.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2013/02/04/how-to-manually-decode-an-activesync-wbxml-stream/